# MySQL JOIN Query crash

Tags: mysql

I'm pretty confused by the behavior of my DBMS with my queries, that's why i need some help.

I have 3 differents tables :

```
 T1 org_info  (routing , job_id)
 VALUES ('|1111|2222|','1300');

 T2 aff_info  (job_id , employee_id , dbegin)
 VALUES('1300','0153','10/02/2017');

 T3 pers_info (employee_id , name)
 VALUES('0153','Gates');
```

The post_info table keeps every record on who was on the job so the aim of my query is to get the last recent person on this job.

Here is my query :

```
SELECT distinct a.employee_id   AS Mat, 
                o.routing       AS Routing,
                o.job_id        AS Job,
                p.last_name     AS Name,
                a.job_id        AS Job2,
                a.dbegin        AS Date_begin
                FROM org_info o

                INNER JOIN aff_info a
                ON o.job_id = a.job_id

                INNER JOIN(
                SELECT MAX(dbegin_post) AS dmax, job_id
                FROM aff_info 
                GROUP BY job_id) b
                ON a.job_id = b.job_id

                INNER JOIN pers_info p
                ON a.employee_id = p.employee_id

                WHERE a.dbegin = dmax
                AND o.routing LIKE '%2222%'
                AND a.job_id= 1300 <!-- Works only with this parameter-->
```

If i delete last parameter it crashs with this error :

> *Query execution was interrupted*

I hope to explain it clearly *this time :)

Thanks

Comment: See [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: It's unclear what the context of the second `INNER JOIN` code snippet is. Does this replace the `INNER JOIN` listed above, is it in addition to?

Comment: No one can help you if no one can understand you.  What's the relationship between query 1 and query2???  And where's the rest of query 2?  Query staring with the clause `INNER JOIN` will definitely not work.

Comment: I think your table size is too huge to run this query on the whole database. when you run it against a single job_id it ran successfully due to fewer records.